# How do I divide my outline slide into two slides?

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I have a large outline in my beamer presentation. I need to divide it in two slides. How should I do it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title[title]{My Full Title}
\author[RPS]{Rudresh Dwivedi \\ Supervisor: Dr. Somnath Dey}
\institute[ ]{Indian Institute of Technology Indore}
\date{\today}

\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bilder/example.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\section[Introduction]{Introduction}
\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[]}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
    Three forms of user authentication:
        Knowledge base
        Tokens
        Biometric: physiological and behavioral characteristics 
\end{frame}
\section[problem1]{Solution to problem1}
\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\end{frame}
\subsection[problem1]{Results to problem1}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\end{frame}
\subsection[problem1]{Conclusion to problem1}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\end{frame}


\section[problem2]{Solution to problem 2}
\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah

\subsection[problem 2]{Results to problem 2}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\end{frame}
\subsection[problem 2]{Conclusion to problem 2}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\end{frame}

\section[problem3]{Solution to problem 3}
\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah

\subsection[problem 3]{Results to problem3}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\end{frame}
\subsection[problem 3]{Conclusion to problem3}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\end{frame}

\section[Related]{ Related work}
\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\section[Proposed work]{ Proposed work}
\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\section{Future work}
\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Reference}
    \begin{tiny}
            \printbibliography
    \end{tiny}
\end{frame}
\section[Thank you]{Thank you}
\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\subsection{Any questions?}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{figure}[!htp]
        \centering
          Thank you image
%         \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{Bilder/thanku.pdf}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @epR8GaYuh my outline is not just a frame. I have created sections and subsections. Please see the MWE before answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Sam Carters solution: you might avoid having two slides, by using two columns of text on one slide.  Of course, this solution works only with relatively small section titles and only with a maximum of nine `\section`s in your document.

```
%% Modiefied from Sam Carters solution
\AtBeginSection{%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Outline}
   \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.49\linewidth}
         \tableofcontents[sections=1-4, currentsection]
      \end{column}\hfill%
      \begin{column}{0.49\linewidth}
          \tableofcontents[sections=5-9, currentsection]
      \end{column}
   \end{columns}
\end{frame}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are a couple of possibilities, I would suggest to split the toc manually using `\tableofcontents[sections=1-4]`.

To automatically display the toc at the start of a section, you can use `\AtBeginSection{...`, but I guess it becomes annoying to always display multiple slides...

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection{%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sections=1-4, currentsection]
    \framebreak
    \tableofcontents[sections=5-9, currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

% possibility 1a: manual breakpoint; gives you the most control
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sections=1-4]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sections=5-9]
\end{frame}

% possibility 1b:
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sections=1-4]
    \framebreak
    \tableofcontents[sections=5-9]
\end{frame}

% possibility 2: automatic break, might not give nice breakpoints
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{sec1}\frame{}
\section{sec2}\frame{}
\section{sec3}\frame{}
\section{sec4}\frame{}
\section{sec5}\frame{}
\section{sec6}\frame{}
\section{sec7}\frame{}
\section{sec8}\frame{}
\section{sec9}\frame{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the changes in my MWE

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi I showed a couple of possibilities. In your not so minimal example, you have to modify the line `\frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[]}` and the outlines at the start of your sections by whatever solution you like.

Comment: in that case that will appear always. If i write \frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[]}, only that section gets highlighted before the start.